# R SQLite converts char to numeric when using COUNT

Tags: r, sqlite

I'm summarising a SQLite database table through R, however when I use COUNT() it is converting my character field to numeric, i.e. if I have observations `0, 1, 2, n` I'm getting `0, 1, 2, 0` back. I've tried the query in SQLite Manager for Firefox, which works as expected; so I expect the issue is to do with RSQLite.

He's a working example of the problem:

```
install.packages("RSQLite")
library(RSQLite)

# Connect
db = dbConnect(SQLite(), "~/Desktop/test.sqlite")

# Make a table
dbSendQuery(db, "
   CREATE TABLE data
      (Year INT,
      Station TXT,
      Obs TXT)
")

# Generate dummy data
x = data.frame(Year=rep(1995:2004, 100),
    Station=rep(c("Bob", "Ringo", "Jarrett", "Heron"), 250),
    Obs=rep(c(0:3, "n"), 200))

# Write dummy data to db
dbWriteTable(db, "data", x, append=T, row.names=F)

# Get summary of data back
y = dbGetQuery(db, "
   SELECT Year, Station, Obs, COUNT(Obs) AS num FROM data
   GROUP BY Year, Station, Obs
")
```

I'd like to know:

1. **Why is it doing this?**
2. **How can I fix it?**

I'm using: R 3.2.2, RStudio 0.99.489, Ubuntu 14.04, RSQLite 1.0.0 & DBI 0.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that happened is that the `Obs` column was declared to be of type `TXT` which is not a builtin type.  If it had been declared as type `TEXT` it would have worked as expected.

In SQLite the type of a column is only a hint and each row of that column can still have a different type.  Since `TXT` is not a known type that is in fact what happens.  In the example below the `txt` and `txt2` columns are declared to have type `TXT` in the `CREATE` statement and `TXT` is not a builtin type in SQLite (`TEXT` is).  As we see in the `y` output below the `typeof(txt)` column showing the type of each row of the `txt` column does have different types for different rows.  Ditto for the `txt2` column as shown in the `typeof(txt2)` column.   When such data is read back into R the first entry is used by R as the type thus `txt` having a first entry of `0` with ijnteger type is read into R as integer and `txt2` having a first entry of `n` with text type is read into R as character.  This can be seen by looking at the `str(y)` output below.  We also note that the `text` column is read into R as character since `text` is a known datatype in SQLite.

```
library(RSQLite)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbSendQuery(db, "CREATE TABLE d (txt TXT, txt2 TXT, text TEXT)")
x <- data.frame(txt = c(0, "n"), txt2 = c("n", 0), text2 = c(0, "n")) 
dbWriteTable(db, "d", x, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)

y <- dbGetQuery(db, 
         "select txt, typeof(txt), txt2, typeof(txt2), text, typeof(text) from d")

y
##  txt typeof(txt) txt2 typeof(txt2) text typeof(text)
## 1   0     integer    n         text    0         text
## 2   0        text    0      integer    n         text

str(y)
## 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  6 variables:
## $ txt         : int  0 0   <------ becomes int since 1st entry of txt is int
## $ typeof(txt) : chr  "integer" "text"
## $ txt2        : chr  "n" "0"  <---- chr since 1st entry is text
## $ typeof(txt2): chr  "text" "integer"
## $ text        : chr  "0" "n"  <--- chr since column declared as text in create
## $ typeof(text): chr  "text" "text"
```

For more info see the [sqlite documentation on datatypes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: Excellent and thorough. Amazing how a little typo/paste mistake can propagate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `CREATE TABLE` command. It should be `TEXT` not `TXT`:

```
dbSendQuery(db, "
   CREATE TABLE data
      (Year INT,
      Station TEXT,
      Obs TEXT)
")
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!